# Right Click for Flag Minesweeper

Tags: javascript, minesweeper

I am building a minesweeper game. I followed a tutorial to get the basics. Then also used some help here for alternating colors. My next problem is that I am stuck on the right click for flag. I have tried using "context menu" then using e.preventDefault(). However, it still does not work. For reference, here is the code.

```js
var board = [];
var rows = 10;
var columns = 10;

var minesCount = 10;
var minesLocation = [];

var tilesClicked = 0; 
var flagEnabled = false;

var gameOver = false;

window.onload = function() {
    startGame();
}

function setMines() {

    let minesLeft = minesCount;
    while (minesLeft > 0) { 
        let r = Math.floor(Math.random() * rows);
        let c = Math.floor(Math.random() * columns);
        let id = r.toString() + "-" + c.toString();

        if (!minesLocation.includes(id)) {
            minesLocation.push(id);
            minesLeft -= 1;
        }
    }
}


function startGame() {
    document.getElementById("mines-count").innerText = minesCount;
    document.getElementById("board").addEventListener("contextmenu", e=> {
        e.preventDefault();
        setFlag();
    });
    setMines();

    for (let r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
        let row = [];
        for (let c = 0; c < columns; c++) {
            let tile = document.createElement("div");
            tile.id = r.toString() + "-" + c.toString();
            tile.addEventListener("click", clickTile);
            document.getElementById("board").append(tile);
            row.push(tile);
        }
        board.push(row);
    }

    console.log(board);
}

function setFlag() {
    if (flagEnabled) {
        flagEnabled = false;
        document.getElementById("flag-button").style.backgroundColor = "lightgray";
    }
    else {
        flagEnabled = true;
        document.getElementById("flag-button").style.backgroundColor = "darkgray";
    }
}

function clickTile() {
    if (gameOver || this.classList.contains("tile-clicked")) {
        return;
    }

    let tile = this;
    if (flagEnabled) {
        if (tile.innerText == "") {
            tile.innerText = "";
        }
        else if (tile.innerText == "") {
            tile.innerText = "";
        }
        return;
    }

    if (minesLocation.includes(tile.id)) {
        gameOver = true;
        revealMines();
        return;
    }


    let coords = tile.id.split("-");
    let r = parseInt(coords[0]);
    let c = parseInt(coords[1]);
    checkMine(r, c);

}

function revealMines() {
    for (let r= 0; r < rows; r++) {
        for (let c = 0; c < columns; c++) {
            let tile = board[r][c];
            if (minesLocation.includes(tile.id)) {
                tile.innerText = "";
                tile.style.backgroundColor = "red";                
            }
        }
    }
}

function checkMine(r, c) {
    if (r < 0 || r >= rows || c < 0 || c >= columns) {
        return;
    }
    if (board[r][c].classList.contains("tile-clicked")) {
        return;
    }

    board[r][c].classList.add("tile-clicked");
    tilesClicked += 1;

    let minesFound = 0;

    minesFound += checkTile(r-1, c-1);      //top left
    minesFound += checkTile(r-1, c);        //top 
    minesFound += checkTile(r-1, c+1);      //top right

    minesFound += checkTile(r, c-1);        //left
    minesFound += checkTile(r, c+1);        //right

    minesFound += checkTile(r+1, c-1);      //bottom left
    minesFound += checkTile(r+1, c);        //bottom 
    minesFound += checkTile(r+1, c+1);      //bottom right

    if (minesFound > 0) {
        board[r][c].innerText = minesFound;
        board[r][c].classList.add("x" + minesFound.toString());
    }
    else {
        checkMine(r-1, c-1);    //top left
        checkMine(r-1, c);      //top
        checkMine(r-1, c+1);    //top right

        checkMine(r, c-1);      //left
        checkMine(r, c+1);      //right

        checkMine(r+1, c-1);    //bottom left
        checkMine(r+1, c);      //bottom
        checkMine(r+1, c+1);    //bottom right
    }

    if (tilesClicked == rows * columns - minesCount) {
        document.getElementById("mines-count").innerText = "Cleared";
        gameOver = true;
    }

}


function checkTile(r, c) {
    if (r < 0 || r >= rows || c < 0 || c >= columns) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (minesLocation.includes(r.toString() + "-" + c.toString())) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  #board {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    border: 10px solid darkgray;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  
  #board div {
    --primary-lightness: 58%;
    --secondary-lightness: 55%;
    --hue: 80deg;
    --sat: 63%;
    --lightness: var(--primary-lightness);
    background-color: hsl(var(--hue) var(--sat) var(--lightness));
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;

    font-size: 30px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  
  #board div:nth-child(odd) {
    --lightness: var(--secondary-lightness);
  }
  
  #board div:is(:nth-child(20n+2), :nth-child(20n+4), :nth-child(20n+6), :nth-child(20n+8), :nth-child(20n+10)) {
    --lightness: var(--secondary-lightness);
  }
  
  #board div:is(:nth-child(20n+1), :nth-child(20n+3), :nth-child(20n+5), :nth-child(20n+7), :nth-child(20n+9)) {
    --lightness: var(--primary-lightness);
  }
  
  #board .tile-clicked {
    --primary-lightness: 76%;
    --secondary-lightness: 72%;
    --hue: 30deg;
    --sat: 57%;
    --lightness: var(--primary-lightness);
  }
  
  .x1 {
    color: blue;
  }
  
  .x2 {
    color: green;
  }
  
  .x3 {
    color: red;
  }
  
  .x4 {
    color: navy;
  }
  
  .x5 {
    color: brown;
  }
  
  .x6 {
    color: teal;
  }
  
  .x7 {
    color: black;
  }
  
  .x8 {
    color: gray;
  }
  
  #flag-button {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 30px;
    background-color: lightgray;
    border: none;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Minesweeper</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="minesweeper.css">
        <script src="minesweeper.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Mines: <span id="mines-count">0</span></h1>
        <div id="board"></div>
        <br>
        <button id="flag-button"></button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Sorry if this is a rookie mistake. I am still pretty new to the language.

Comment: The terms `contextmenu` and `preventDefault` don't appear anywhere in that code.

Comment: Yea. Had an old default in my copy paste. I edited it.

Comment: That code should work as per the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/contextmenu_event). Can you provide your HTML also so we have a MCVE?

Comment: yea, ill put the CSS as well

Comment: For some reason this code crashes my browser tab when I run it on jsfiddle. Is it just me?

Comment: I have this running in VSCode. Running with Live Server in Google Chrome.

Comment: I just put your new code in a Stack Snippet here, and it works fine for me. Does it work for you here?

Comment: It runs for me. I don't know if you can see it. However, when I right click, I have to click once more to place a flag. Is there a way around that?

Comment: I mean does the flag color changing happen, not just does it run?

Comment: The button changes color. Its an indication that right click is working. Just not in the way I want it too.

Comment: Wait, what exactly do you want it to do then?

Comment: I want it just to place a flag when I right click. However, currently, I have to right click, then left click on the tile I want to flag.